# How to add numbers to be stored in a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the problem I have to solve : Write a program to sum a series of numbers entered by the user. The program should first prompt the user for how many numbers are to be summed. It should then input each of the numbers and print a total sum. This is what I have so far:

```
def excercise13():

print("Programming Excercise 13")
print("This program adds a series of numbers.")
while True:
    try:
        numberTimes = float(input("Enter how many numbers will be added: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input.")
    else:
        break
numberTimes = int(numberTimes)
while True:
    try:
        for i in range(1,(numberTimes+1)):
            ("""I don't know what to put here""")
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input.")
    else:
        break
totalSum =
print("The sum of",nums,"is:",totalSum)
print()

excercise13()
```

Comment: Folks aren't here to do your homework.  If you have a specific question, you should ask it clearly.  That said, why wouldn't you use `input()` to get the numbers just like you used it to read how many numbers need to be summed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will go through the solution, based on your code, code block by code block.

```
def excercise13():

    currentnumber = 0
```

Here we create the function `excercise13()` and set `currentnumber` to 0

```
    print("Programming Excercise 13")
    print("This program adds a series of numbers.")
    while True:
        try:
            numberTimes = int(input("Enter how many numbers will be added: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input.")
        else:
            break
```

You should use `int` instead of `float.` Can you imagine doing a process 3.5 times? This also reduces your previous repetition.

```
    for x in range(numbertimes): #More pythonic way.
        new_number = input ("Please enter a number to be added.")
        currentnumber += new_number
```

The above code block makes the program ask for a new number `numbertimes` times. It then adds this number to `currentnumber`

```
    totalSum = currentnumber
    print("The sum of",nums,"is:",totalSum)
    print()
```

This sets the `totalSum` to the final `currentnumber`

```
excercise13()
```

This starts your code.

Answer (score 0):

Python has this functionality built in as the `sum` function.

```
def makesum():    
    try:
        numbers = input('Enter the numbers to sum, comma seperated: ')
        print 'The sum is {0}'.format(sum(numbers))
    except:
        print 'Input invalid. Try again.'
        makesum()

makesum()
```